# Why can't python suddenly not run functions from imported modules?

Tags: python, module, path, sys, sys.path

I have some weird problems with python, and I don't know how to fix it.

For the following code:
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)`

I get the error:
`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'`

The same happens with other modules. Another example:
`L = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)`

Gives the error:
`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'sqrt'`

I suspect that I might have managed to mess up my paths?

When I try to print my sys.path, this is what happens:

```
import sys

sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:653 in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]

KeyError: 'type_printers'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:706 in __call__
    type_pprinters=self.type_printers,

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:700 in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:656 in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:1868 in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:1229 in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:686 in _type_printers_default
    d[numpy.float64] = lambda obj, p, cycle: p.text(self.float_format % obj)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float64'
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you happen to have a script file call `numpy.py` in your project or perhaps fome other file that conflicts with a library?

Comment: no, no other file called numpy.py

Comment: Please add the version number of Python and numpy. Additionally do `import numpy` followed by `print(numpy.__file__)` and give us the output as well.

Comment: It looks like you're using the base conda environment instead of having created one specific for this project. It's always best to create an environment for each project, to make it easier to wipe and re-create when it gets messed up. I would try a creating a fresh environment and installing things in it. If that fails, show us the steps used to create it and we'll be able to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the DataFrame class is not being found within the pandas module.
Make sure that you have installed the pandas library correctly. You can use the following command to install or upgrade pandas:

`pip install --upgrade pandas`

Also Make sure there are no other files named pandas.py or variables named pandas in the same directory as your script. This can cause conflicts and prevent the correct pandas module from being imported.

Comment: thanks, but there is no other file named pandas and pandas is upgraded.

Comment: Can you share requirements file by running the command `pip freeze` in the activated environment ?